# Find the Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

[image]

I am trying to find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is the Jordan canonical form. But I am getting confused. I found the characteristic polynomial to be $(x-1)(x-2)^5$ and minimum polynomial to be $(x-1)(x-2)^3$. The eigenvectors that are related to 2 are $v_1=(-4,0,2,2,2,0),v_2=(9,1,-5,-4,0,2)$ and that is related to 1 is $v_3=(36,0,-18,-18,-9,4)$.

Now I believe Jordan form should have five 2s and one 1 on the diagonal and two 1s on the lower diagonal.

I am kind of confused how to get the columns of $P$. I think the last column should be the eigenvector of 1. I thought I had to solve $(A-2I)x_1=v_1$ then find a vector x_1. Then solve $(A-2I)x_2=x_1$ and find vector x_2 until I get a nonlinear vector and then do the same thing for $v_2$. But It doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest to do some similar exercise with matrix with small size. The algorithm you have to follow is the same but the computation is not tedius.

Comment: The Jordan form that you’ve described is incorrect. The exponents of the minimal polynomial tell you the maximum size of the Jordan blocks associated with each eigenvalue, and the number of linearly-independent eigenvalues tells you how many blocks there will be. Seems like you’ve got one block too many, or miscounted their sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done carefully, your method should work. The denominators come out a little large. I prefer this: columns I wil cal $u,v,w,x,y,z.$ $z$ is the far right column, solves $(A-2I)^3 z = 0$ but $(A-2I)^2 z \neq 0.$ I picked $z = (0,1,0,0,0,0)^T.$ Next $y = (A-2I)z$ and $x = (A-2I)y$ is automatically an eigenvector.  Next, $w $ independent from $y$ with $(A-2I)^2w = 0$ but $(A-2I)w \neq 0.$  I chose $w = (0,0,0,1,0,0)^T.$ Then $x = (A-2I)w$ is another eigenvector. Finally, the far left column is $u,$ your eigenvector for $1.$ Put columns $u,v,w,x,y,z$ as $P,$ the determinant comes out $8,$ so $P^{-1}$ is $1/8$ times an integer matrix.

Comment: Ah It worked, thank you a lot! What is the reason we picked those powers to find z and w?